# Stable Marriage stack issues

Tags: java, algorithm

I need help. I am working on the Gale-Shapely Stable Marriage problem in Java. Code below. This is the "break up and remarry" portion. The issue is that a phantom man comes into the picture (I have man 0-9 on the stack and somewhere a man 10 comes into it). I have discovered it is because I am putting into the stack the man's actual number rather than his position (Which is a difference of 1. i.e. putting in man1 rather than man1's position of 0).

However, if I remedy this by putting in what should be in there ((temp-1)) I get an infinite loop... Below is the portion that should work with the right values but gives me an infinite loop. So my question: Why does decrementing temp result in not only an infinite loop, but ridiculous outputs that I can't begin to describe here? And how can push the correct value on to the stack?

```
public void Test(){
    StdOut.println("Stack size = "+stack.size());
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        int man= stack.pop();
        StdOut.println("man="+man);
        for(int woman=0;woman<N;woman++){
            int preferenceplace = M[man][woman];

            if(statusW[(preferenceplace-1)]==0){
                statusM[man] = preferenceplace;

                statusW[(preferenceplace-1)] = (man+1);
                break;
            }
            else{
                if(statusW[(preferenceplace-1)]!=0){

                    int JonnyLately = findPref(N,man,woman);

                    int Fiance = findPref(N,statusW[preferenceplace-1],woman);

                    if(Fiance<JonnyLately){
                        //  StdOut.println("She's happy. Move on");
                    }
                    else if(Fiance>JonnyLately){

                        int temp = W[woman][Fiance];
                        StdOut.println(temp+" is free now");
                        statusM[(temp-1)]=0;
                        stack.push((temp-1));
                        statusW[(preferenceplace-1)]=(man+1);
                        statusM[man]= preferenceplace;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you need to include a bit more code. No-one can see what's on your stack when you come into this method, what the dimensions and contents of your arrays are... so it's about impossible to help you diagnose anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't clear.but I think you are decrementing in wrong place.
Try this

```
for(int woman=0;woman<N;woman++){
        int preferenceplace = M[man-1][woman];
```